# debugging magento code on xampp using netbeans and xdebug

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to debug Magento code for learning Magento. I have Magento installed on XAMPP (windows XP sp2).I have installed Netbeans(php version) and configured xdebug.

In netbeans I selected `"php application with existing sources"`.Then I created a folder `"myFolder"` in `C:\xampp\htdocs` for the purpose of exporting the Magento code .

Now I want to know that In the `'name and location panel'`(in Netbeans) would setting the `"source folder"` field to `"C:\xampp\htdocs\magento"` be right('Magento' is the directory under which Magento is installed)?

Also what should I enter in the `"copy to folder"` field under the `"run configuration"` panel, should I enter `"C:\xampp\htdocs\myFolder"` and if I do this then would the entire Magento code would be exported to `"myFolder"`.

Please help I would be very thankful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not about Magento.

Comment: I have the same issue.. can't debug magento.. would be great if someone answer this even it looks off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

In order to debug PHP scripts in NetBeans, you need to :

- Install the XDebug extension: Download the correct .dll from http://xdebug.org/download.php and copy it into your D:\xampp\php\ext directory
- Add the following lines to your php.ini file:

  ```
  [XDebug]
  zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\your_php_xdebug.dll"
  xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
  xdebug.remote_enable = 1
  xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
  xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
  xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
  ```
- Restart the Apache webserver
- From NetBeans Tools->Options->Debugging, set Debugger port and Session ID to 9000 and netbeans-xdebug respectively. Create a run configuration and hit the Debug button.